# Python - Remove a row from numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hi all what I wan't should be really simple for somebody here..I want to remove a row from a numpy array in a loop like:

```
for i in range(len(self.Finalweight)):
        if self.Finalweight[i] >= self.cutoffOutliers:
            "remove line[i from self.wData"
```

I'm trying to remove outliers from a dataset. My full code os the method is like:

```
def calculate_Outliers(self):
    def calcWeight(Value):
        pFinal = abs(Value - self.pMed)/ self.pDev_abs_Med
        gradFinal = abs(gradient(Value) - self.gradMed) / self.gradDev_abs_Med
        return pFinal * gradFinal

    self.pMed = median(self.wData[:,self.yColum-1])
    self.pDev_abs_Med = median(abs(self.wData[:,self.yColum-1] - self.pMed))
    self.gradMed = median(gradient(self.wData[:,self.yColum-1]))
    self.gradDev_abs_Med = median(abs(gradient(self.wData[:,self.yColum-1]) - self.gradMed))    
    self.workingData= self.wData[calcWeight(self.wData)<self.cutoffOutliers]

    self.xData = self.workingData[:,self.xColum-1]
    self.yData = self.workingData[:,self.yColum-1]
```

I'm getting the following error:

ile "bin/dmtools", line 201, in plot_gride
    self.calculate_Outliers()
  File "bin/dmtools", line 188, in calculate_Outliers
    self.workingData= self.wData[calcWeight(self.wData)>self.cutoffOutliers]
ValueError: too many indices for array

Comment: If you are removing a lot of elements it would probably be faster to just create a new array and fill it with the values that pass the cutoff.  Each call to remove with a numpy array will force a lot of value swaps to move all of the elements after the deleted index down.  Also, your loop won't work if you are removing elements.

Comment: @Canesin: OK, do the logic construction in a loop (if really necessary, but most probable it could also be vectorized) and then in one step (as I suggested) construct a new array based on your conditions.

Comment: @Canesin: So it seems that your `for i in range(...` construction could be replaced with simple statement `self.wData= self.wData[self.Finalweight>= self.cutoffOutliers] Right? An other observation, if your calculation variables are temporal in nature there is no need to treat them as instance variables. Thanks

Comment: @eat: self.wData= self.wData[self.Finalweight>= self.cutoffOutliers]  give [] but I'm sure many rowns in wData statisfy

Comment: @Canesin: How can you be sure, if you haven't implemented yet your `for i in range(... construct`? Anyway these are my guidelines in general how to avoid deleting rows, columns, or elements of `numpy`-array in loops. I haven't considered your actual `self.Finalweight` calculation logic at all. Please clarify if my suggested way to handle 'deleting items' from `numpy`-array is no way applicable to you. Thanks

Comment: @eat: I have a sample dataset I have played a little in the console with it first...  I'm trying to use the approach you have provided... Will edit to show the error I'm getting now

Comment: @Canesin: I'm sorry but I'm not able to help with your actual debugging. (Perhaps I shouldn't ask you to provide some real world example at the first place (:. Anyway I would now suggest to go back to your original question: How to remove a row from `numpy`-array. Do you see the logic behind my answer? Would you be able to apply it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a tool in NumPy specifically made to mask out outliers and invalid data points: [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html).  Example from the linked page:

```
x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, -1, 5])
mx = numpy.ma.masked_array(x, mask=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
print mx.mean()
```

prints

```
2.75
```

Comment: You could also do it simply using `x[x!=-1].mean()`.